# How to Make document Short Cut in windows without using Pywin Module

Tags: python, windows

I have list of files and General Names of files stored in a textfile.

I like to use this to make some shortcuts in windows.

Although in my company I cannot access the Py Win Module. I was wondering if there is an Easy workaround to do this in Python. Or if I have to look at other languages

There is a lot of Doucmention for the VBA side , but I m very much a novice using this language

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fywyxt64

Can this be done with Python Without using Py Win ?

Comment: can you ask for permission to get `pywin`?

Comment: You can probably do what you need by using the [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes) module to make direct call to the OS to do what you want.

Comment: Can you install a [PyWin32 wheel](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32) in a virtual environment via pip?

Comment: @martineau, I wouldn't recommend using COM interfaces directly via `ctypes`; it's hard enough with the help of `comtypes`.

Comment: i can t access to pywin at all. At work its pretty much locked down Importing any other modules is impossible . So the solution needs to be a stand alone one inside Python existing libraries